# Complex - Entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove this. I could not use $\Im(w)<0$ condition in Liouville's theorem.

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and assuming that $f(z)$ does not take values in $\Im(w)<0$ show that $f$ is identically zero.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to assume non-constant.

Comment: Consider $g\circ f$ where $g$ is a suitable fractional linear transformation.

Comment: What can you say about $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{f(z)+i}$.

Comment: How g can be used in thm ?

Comment: $g$ is bounded and entire. What can you say about such functions? And what does that say about $f$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(z)=e^{if(z)}$. Then $g$ is entire and $$|g(z)|=|\exp((\Re f(z)+i\Im f(z))i)|
=|\exp\left(i\Re f(z)-\Im f(z)\right)|=e^{-\Im f(z)}\leq 1.$$
By Liouville theorem, $g$ is constant hence $e^{if(z)}=C$ and $f'(z)e^{if(z)}=0$ so $f$ is constant (but not necessarily $0$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$   is non constant. Then $\mathcal{Im}(f)$ is open so we can assume $\mathcal{Im}(f) \subset I(w) > 0$

$ \varphi :z \mapsto \frac{z - i }{z + i}$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{D}$ to $I(w) > 0$

So $\varphi^{-1} \circ f $ is an entire function which is bounded so by Liouville it is constant and then $f$ is constant.