# Prooving that a complex function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=u(z)+v(z)i$, $u(z) \leq 0 , \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, and $f(z)$ is entire. Then $f(z)$ is constant.
The  hint is "use the Liouville theorem". I tried , but i need prove which f is limited first, and i don't know how.

Comment: Compose $f$ with an invertible transformation $T$ such that $g = T\circ f$ is bounded.

Comment: Are we assuming that $f$ is holomorphic / analytic?

Answer (score 3):

Let $g$ be a map (a Moebius transformation) that sends the open half-plane $\Re(z)<0$ to the open unit disk biholomorphically. Then $g\circ f$ is a bounded holomorphic function and so is constant. Since $g$ is a bijection, $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Or easier, just look att $e^f$.

Comment: @mrf, nice! Consider adding it as an answer.

Comment: Nah, it's been asked and answered **many** times, for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153815).